# Dynamically adding table row with JQuery sets small row height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using  Jquery code to add new row in the table tblPros with two new cells with couple of elements. The result what I got is a row with small height. I am using the same HTML code  to add the previous rows, but there is not issues with table height.  How can I change that?

The JQuery code that  I am using to add dynamically new row to the table is:

```
    $("#tblPros")
    .append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>')
            .append($('<div>')
                .attr('class', 'info-block block-info clearfix')
                .append($('<div>')
                .attr('data-toggle', 'buttons')
                .attr('class', 'btn-group bizmoduleselect')
                .attr('style', 'width:100%')
                .append($('<label>')
                .attr('class', 'btn btn-default')
                .attr('style', 'width:100%')
                .append($('<div>')
                .attr('class', 'bizcontent')
                .append($('<input>')
                .attr('type', 'checkbox')
                .attr('name', name)
                .attr('class', 'Pros')
                .attr('value', name)
                  .attr('style', 'width:400px')
                  .append($('<h5>')
                  .text(name))))))))

                  .append($('<div>').attr('width', '50%'))).attr('height', '100%');
```

Original HTML code what i used to add previous checkboxes is:

```
                            <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">
                                <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect" style="width:100%">
                                    <label class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%">
                                        <div class="bizcontent">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Durable" class="Pros" value="Durable">
                                            <h5>Durable</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="50%">

                            <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">
                                <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect" style="width:100%">
                                    <label class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%">
                                        <div class="bizcontent">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Versatile" class="Pros" value="Versatile">
                                            <h5>Versatile</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
```

The result what I got is a grey row with small height and it is shown on the picture : [image: Result after adding the new row]

Comment: Why are you appending an extra div at the end in your code? That doesn't exist in the HTML examples. And it's invalid HTML to add a div which is inside a table,but not inside a td

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to close the bracket after your input element. With your current jquery code it has output like,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Versatile" class="Pros" value="Versatile">
    <h5>Versatile</h5>
</input>
```

**UPDATE**

Your code should be like;

```
$("#tblPros")
.append($('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>')
        .append($('<div>')
            .attr('class', 'info-block block-info clearfix')
            .append($('<div>')
            .attr('data-toggle', 'buttons')
            .attr('class', 'btn-group bizmoduleselect')
            .attr('style', 'width:100%')
            .append($('<label>')
            .attr('class', 'btn btn-default')
            .attr('style', 'width:100%')
            .append($('<div>')
            .attr('class', 'bizcontent')
            .append($('<input>')
            .attr('type', 'checkbox')
            .attr('name', name)
            .attr('class', 'Pros')
            .attr('value', name)
            .attr('style', 'width:400px'))
            .append($('<h5>')
            .text(name)))))))
            .append($('<div>').attr('width', '50%'))).attr('height', '100%');
```

Changed row: .attr('style', 'width:400px'))

Comment: Thanks a lot @Serdar, I find the solution with your hint !The <h5> element should be outside of <input> element. So i added only only one closing parenthesis and all works fine !!! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution. I missed one closing parenthesis in my jquery code. The  element was inside the element and that was the whole mistake (thanks @Serdar). So, I solved the problem by  setting new closing parenthesis in my jquery code just before adding the  element.

The new JQuery code is:

```js
   $("#tblPros")
        .append($('<tr>')
            .append($('<td>')
                .append($('<div>')
                    .attr('class', 'info-block block-info clearfix')
                    .append($('<div>')
                    .attr('data-toggle', 'buttons')
                    .attr('class', 'btn-group bizmoduleselect')
                    .attr('style', 'width:100%')
                    .append($('<label>')
                    .attr('class', 'btn btn-default')
                    .attr('style', 'width:100%')
                    .append($('<div>')
                    .attr('class', 'bizcontent')
                    .append($('<input>')
                    .attr('type', 'checkbox')
                    .attr('name', name)
                    .attr('class', 'Pros')
                    .attr('value', name)
                      .attr('style', 'width:400px')
                      ).append($('<h5>')
                      .text(name)))))))

                      .append($('<div>').attr('width', '50%'))).attr('height', '100%');
```

The solution/result of this change looks like this:
[image]